# How to build dynamic SQL query inside stored procedure using input parameters?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

We have a requirement where we need to build SQL query depending upon the inputs received to stored procedure. For the sake of simplicity I have reduced number of fields in input and select. Facing error mentioned below.

Can you please help me resolve this error and let me know how can I execute this query.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MYAPP_AUDIT_GET_RECORDS
AS
BEGIN
    p_requestnumber    VARCHAR2(256);
    p_username         VARCHAR2(256);
    sql_query          VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
    sql_query := 'select message_type, timestamp, request_number, username, useraction, component_name, module_name, process_name, task, version, response_code, response_message, audit_message from myapp_audit where ';

    if p_username is not null and p_requestnumber is not null then
        sql_query := sql_query || 'username = ' :p_username ' and request_number = ' :p_requestnumber;
    elsif p_username is null and p_requestnumber is not null then
        sql_query := sql_query || 'request_number =' :p_requestnumber;
    else
        sql_query := sql_query || 'username = ' :username;
    end if;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sql_query);
END MYAPP_AUDIT_GET_RECORDS;
```

Error:

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "VARCHAR2" when expecting one of the following:     := . ( @ % ; The symbol ":=" was substituted for "VARCHAR2" to continue.
> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "," when expecting one of the following:     . ( * % & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem    <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2    like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset

Comment: The error is nothing to do with the dynamic SQL. As the error says, the commas after the first two variable declarations are wrong - they should be semicolons. But In the dynamic part the bind placeholders (`:p_username` etc.) should be inside the string literals - you currently have extra quotes; and you need to actually bind the values when you come to execute (which will require more if/then logic).

Comment: @AlexPoole, after adding semicolons to first declaration, it still throws error 'PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "VARCHAR2"' for all three variable declarations.

Comment: That's because those declarations are after a BEGIN, nor a DECLARE - though you don't want that either for a procedure, as MTO showed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use dynamic SQL when you do not need to:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MYAPP_AUDIT_GET_RECORDS(
  o_cur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS
  p_requestnumber    VARCHAR2(256);
  p_username         VARCHAR2(256);
BEGIN
  OPEN o_cur FOR
    select message_type,
           timestamp,
           request_number,
           username,
           useraction,
           component_name,
           module_name,
           process_name,
           task,
           version,
           response_code,
           response_message,
           audit_message
    FROM   myapp_audit
    WHERE  ( p_username IS NULL OR username = p_username )
    AND    ( p_requestnumber IS NULL OR request_number = p_requestnumber )
    AND    ( p_username IS NOT NULL OR p_requestnumber IS NOT NULL);
END MYAPP_AUDIT_GET_RECORDS;
```

If you do need to use dynamic SQL (you do not in your example) then use bind parameters and **NEVER** use (unsanitised) string concatenation for variables (as that is how you introduce SQL injection vulnerabilities):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MYAPP_AUDIT_GET_RECORDS
AS
  p_requestnumber    VARCHAR2(256);
  p_username         VARCHAR2(256);
  sql_query          VARCHAR2(1000);
  somevariable       AN_APPROPRIATE_DATATYPE;
BEGIN
  sql_query := 'select message_type, timestamp, request_number, username, useraction, component_name, module_name, process_name, task, version, response_code, response_message, audit_message from myapp_audit where ';

  if p_username is not null and p_requestnumber is not null then
    sql_query := sql_query || 'username = :username and request_number = :requestnumber';
  elsif p_username is null and p_requestnumber is not null then
    sql_query := sql_query || ':username IS NULL AND request_number = :requestnumber';
  else
    sql_query := sql_query || 'username = :username AND :requestnumber IS NULL';
  end if;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sql_query);
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_query
    BULK COLLECT INTO somevariable
    USING p_username, p_requestnumber;
END MYAPP_AUDIT_GET_RECORDS;
```

Comment: @MTO, Thanks a lot. Yes, will refrain from using dynamic SQL going forward.